# How to change size box while click in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I want to change height size of div elements "Container-2". So, when i click button components and got value = 10, height of "Container-2" will change to 100px, previous is 50px.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Tugas9 from './tugas9/tugas9';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Tugas9/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

tugas9.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import './Tugas9.css';

function Tugas9 () {
    const [angka, setAngka] = useState(1);
    const increment = () => {
        setAngka(angka +1);
    }

    return (
        <div className="Container-2">
            <div className="App-2">
                <p>{angka}</p>
                <button onClick={increment}>Tambah</button>
                {angka >= 10 ? <span>State count sudah lebih dari 10!!</span> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tugas9;
```

CSS

```
.Container-2 {
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
  }

  .App-2 p {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .App-2 button {
    padding: 5px 375px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .App-2 span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

I've tried many ways, but still didn't work. I'm also a beginner with React JS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about the `useEffect()` hook? It allows you to respond to the changes of state in your app.

Here's how it could solve your problem. First, you define the height of the box as a state:

```
const [boxHeight, setBoxHeight] = useState(50)
```

and then use inline styling to define the height of the box:

```
<div className="Container-2" style={{height: `${boxHeight}px`}}>
...
```

Now, the last thing we need to do is to change the height whenever `angka` state is more than `10`. Let's use the `useEffect()` hook to achieve it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (angka >= 10) {
    setBoxHeight(100)
  }
}, [angka])
```

If you're not familiar with the `useEffect()` hook, make sure to read the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).